# How to sync my thread and UI thread on android

Tags: android, multithreading

The scenario is, I have a download data thread using callback to update UI(using runOnUIThread method), and user can cancel download data manually(run on main thread). The problem is, when download data thread is finishing download data, in the meantime, a cancel event is triggering by user, so that, the data will update to finish first, then update to cancelled.

The question is, how to sync those threads for updating UI?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like you wanted to use [AsycTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). It enabled you to cancel and update UI thread.

Comment: It sounds like you want the UI thread to update a flag that the download thread will read to say that the download is cancelled. The download thread would check this flag before the progress update callback, and if it's set (i.e the user cancelled the download) stop downloading and post a different "canceled" message back to the UI?

Comment: the download thread has two callback methods: onProgressChanged() and onCompleted(). updateUI() method will be triggered in onCompleted() for updating UI elements, and if user cancelled downloading data manually, updateUI() will be triggered as well. I lock a shared sync object for invoking updateUI(), but I wonder if it will be dead lock because updateUI() mehtod using activity.runOnUIThread()?Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

The other thread needs to be checking for cancellation using interrupted() or isInterrupted() methods of thread. You need to have a way of checking status after downloading suitable part of data.